# Comparing 2 arrays for tolerance

Tags: python

What I am trying to do is tax an array, transpose it , subtract the two arrays and then see if the difference of each cell is with a certain tolerance. I am able to get a subtracted array - but I don't know how to cycle through each item to compare the amounts - ideally I would test for floating-point near-equality; and return true - if all items are with a tolerance and false otherwise - not sure how do to this last step as well.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 8],[ 3, 4, 1]])    
b = a.transpose(1, 0)

rows = a.shape[1]
col = a.shape[0]
r = abs(np.subtract(a, b))  # abs value of 2 array

i = 0
while i < rows:
    j = 0
    while j < rows:
        if np.any(r[i][j]) > 3:  # sample using 3 as tolerance
            print("false")
        j += 1
    print("true")
    i += 1
```

Comment: `numpy.allclose` (or something like that)

Comment: (r<3).any() should return true if any of the element is less than 3.

Comment: I am getting closer, i've added 
     q= (np.isclose(a, b, 1e-09, 0.0)) - to check for tollerance  - get an array with boolean values - now all i need to do is to return true if the entire new matrix is true - or false otherwise.. any help with this

Answer (score 3):

Is this not sufficient for your needs?

```
tolerance = 3
result = (abs(a - b) <= tolerance).all()
```

Comment: I am getting closer, i've added

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow? I have edited my answer though to bring it closer into line with the output you wanted. It should be exactly what you want now.

Comment: ultimately what i am after is to compare a matrix with its transpose and see if the difference between the two is within a certain tollerance. I added the following and now get a boolean Matrix, that gives me the correct output -but what I need is a final way to return True if the entire matrix is True - otherwise false. Sorry if i don't explain myself I am new to all of this

Comment: how do i paste my new code - i now have it as a function - tidied things up - your suggestion really helps - just one last problem

Answer (score 0):

In this step

```
r = abs(np.subtract(a, b))
```

you already have a matrix of distances, so all you need to do is apply comparison operator (which in numpy is applied element-wise)

```
errors = r > 3
```

which results in **boolean** array, and if you want to see how many elements have true value, just sum it

```
print( np.sum(r > 3) )
```

and to check if any is wrong, you can just do

```
print( np.sum(r > 3) > 0 ) # prints true iff any element of r is bigger than 3
```

There are also built-in methods, but this reasoning gives you more flexibility in expressing what is "near" or "good".